# running scripts is disabled on this system When I used Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs

create-react-app: File C:\Users\NAFFY KAUSAR\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- create-react-app AvatarAwesome
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```